# How we can get onboard id on basis of stripe account ID?

Tags: stripe-payments, strip, strip-tags

I want to integrate another link from stripe on our backend dashboard for onboarding/linking existing "Standard" accounts.

I just want to create a dynamic onboarding account link like **[https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=https://connect.stripe.com/hosted/oauth&client_id='client_id'&state='onboard_id'&response_type=code&scope=read_write&stripe_user[country]=US](https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=https://connect.stripe.com/hosted/oauth&client_id=%27client_id%27&state=%27onboard_id%27&response_type=code&scope=read_write&stripe_user%5Bcountry%5D=US)** via API

Can anyone please help me to find out the way like how we can get above link in response of API?

I have already tried to check with below link  https://stripe.com/docs/api/account_links/create

Answer (score 0):

If by "account ID" you mean the `client_id` query parameter, then it can be found in your Stripe dashboard at the bottom of the [Connect settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/connect) page. I don't think this can be retrieved with the API, but this ID won't change so you can grab it from the dashboard and store it on your end to reuse it later.

Comment: No i don't want client_id i already know about that i want onboard id which account was in process.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "onboard id"? Is it the account ID, authorization code, access token, something else? You can learn more about OAuth [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference).